# In Python, If I split a string up, how do i check if each part of it is an integer

Tags: python

for example if my input was "1 2 3", how do I check if each part is a integer and not anything else and if there was something else, be able to input the string again so its correct otherwise it wont move on

Comment: So your input is "1 2 3" or separate inputs like "1", "2", "3"?

Comment: It is all on one line separated by spaces

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = "1 2 3"
>>> all([i.isdigit() for i in s.split()])
True

>>> l = "1 b 2 5 c"
>>> all([i.isdigit() for i in l.split()])
False
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham this solves the problem for OP's use case. Until you have reason to believe otherwise, why make the solution more complicated?

Comment: How is explaining to the OP the limitation of use making the solution more complicated?

Answer (score 2):

The following reads from standard input and keeps reading until a string is received with space-separated integers. Finally it prints that it got all integers:

```
s = raw_input('Enter your input:')
while not all((p.isdigit() for p in s.split(" "))):
    print("Not all integers")
    s = raw_input('Enter your input:')
print("Got all integers!")
```

Comment: Note: To make this work in Python 3.x, you'll want to change the `raw_input()` to `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split you string to a list using
     list1=s.split()

And then check wether each of them is a integer or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly code, but it does what you want:

```
import re
integers = re.compile('[^\d\s]')
while True:
    s = input("Enter integers: ")
    if not integers.match(s):
        break
```